# Rebuild .m4a file with ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, codec, m4a

I have a couple of corrupt m4a file that I'd like to try to repair by rebuilding the container, so I thought ffmpeg could do that easily. However, when I run this, even on a valid file, I get an error:

```
>ffmpeg -i "in.m4a" -c:a copy "out.m4a"

[...]

[ipod @ 000001fd30ab52c0] Frame rate very high for a muxer not efficiently supporting it.
Please consider specifying a lower framerate, a different muxer or -vsync 2
[libx264 @ 000001fd30a844c0] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 000001fd30a844c0] MB rate (129960000) > level limit (16711680)
[libx264 @ 000001fd30a844c0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 000001fd30a844c0] profile High, level 6.2, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 000001fd30a844c0] 264 - core 161 r3048 b86ae3c - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2021 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
[ipod @ 000001fd30ab52c0] Could not find tag for codec h264 in stream #0, codec not currently supported in container
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error initializing output stream 0:0 --
Conversion failed!
```

Any idea?